# How to disable toolbar item?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller

How can I disable toolbar item by tag?

I've tried this method:

```
for item in (navigationController?.toolbarItems)! {
    if item.tag == 1 {
        item.enabled = false   
    }
}
```

but I do not know why, it did not work. How can I fix my code?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the items are tagged?

Comment: Can you just NSLog the items you're seeing in the enumeration? Are they UIBarButtonItems? Do they exist at all?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
var items = (navigationController?.toolbar.items)!
for item: UIBarButtonItem in items {
    if item.tag == 1 {
        item.enabled = true
    }
}
```